# traversing a Map generated from OpenCSV

Tags: java, csv, collections, hashmap, opencsv

I have a single column of data, output from `Google Sheets` as `CSV`, and also from `LibreOffice` as `CSV` as well.  I've tried to marshal both files using `OpenCSV` but am only getting a small portion of data available.

How can I read this file in?  I don't really see any commas in this `CSV` file...but it's only a single column of data.

file:

```
thufir@dur:~/jaxb$ 
thufir@dur:~/jaxb$ head input.csv 
Field 1
Foo # 16

bar

baz

fdkfdl

fdsfdsfsdfgh
thufir@dur:~/jaxb$
```

output:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/BaseXFromJAXB$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/BaseXFromJAXB$ gradle run

> Task :run
Jan 10, 2019 3:36:08 PM net.bounceme.dur.basexfromjaxb.csv.ReaderForCVS printMap
INFO: Foo # 16
Jan 10, 2019 3:36:08 PM net.bounceme.dur.basexfromjaxb.csv.ReaderForCVS printMap
INFO: Field 1
Jan 10, 2019 3:36:08 PM net.bounceme.dur.basexfromjaxb.csv.ReaderForCVS printMap
INFO: Foo # 16

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/BaseXFromJAXB$
```

code:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.basexfromjaxb.csv;

import com.opencsv.CSVReaderHeaderAware;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ReaderForCVS {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ReaderForCVS.class.getName());
    private Map<String, String> values;

    public ReaderForCVS() {
    }

    public void unmarshal(URI inputURI) throws Exception {
        FileReader f = new FileReader(new File(inputURI));
        values = new CSVReaderHeaderAware(f).readMap();
    }

    public void printMap() {
        Collection<String> stringValues = values.values();
        for (String s : stringValues) {
            LOG.info(s);
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : values.entrySet()) {
            String key = item.getKey();
            String value = item.getValue();
            LOG.info(key);
            LOG.info(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Frankly, I can't tell whether the library is reading in the file in a funky way, or the file is mangled in someway, or what.  I'll be looking for `CSV` from websites, but not sure what that establishes.  I don't see it likely that the library isn't parsing properly, but neither can I see the problem with this data.

There are only so many ways to export data from a spreadsheet as `CSV` and I've tried a few.  The content of the file is immaterial, but that structure:  lines with no content, just a single column, special characters, is what I'm dealing with.

Reading in the [file as text](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-open-read-file-java-string-array-list) gives the desired output...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it works similar to the other CSVReaders [OpenCSV Guide Reading](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#reading_into_an_array_of_strings). Here is some sample code I used which seemed to work:

```
CSVReaderHeaderAware csvReaderHeaderAware= new CSVReaderHeaderAware(new StringReader(DAOConstants.IND_DATA));
while (((values = (Map<String, String>) csvReaderHeaderAware.readMap())) != null)
{
      for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : values.entrySet())  
            System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());

}
```